How to use show_in_rest = true in ACF?
I'm using Classic Editor with ACF.
When I was using CFS, I described
register_post_type(
 "article",
 array(
  "label" => "記事",
  "public" => true,
  "has_archive" => true,
  "show_in_rest" => true,//here!
  "menu_position" => 5,
  "supports" => array (
   "title",
   "editor",
   "revisions",
  ),
 ),
);

I already tried register_rest_field() but it wasn't answer.
How to use show_in_rest = true in ACF with Classic Editor?
In page, shown Classic Editor.
In post, shown Gutenberg Editor.
That is what I expecting.
Should I create custom block?

hi @bonnacon are you already look official guide https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/wp-rest-api-integration/
and
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/integrating-custom-field-types/
?

I'm sorry for found answer before read that link page...
But thanks for your help :)

next time I will be more quickly

This was caused just a careless mistake...
I was activating the plugin "Classic Editor" so show_in_rest is overwritten by Classic Editor.
When I deactivated the Clasicc Editor, it worked.
I'm sorry for my lack:(
